# Persistance storage for UIVIew

Tags: ios, ipad, storage, data-persistence

I am creating dynamically some "n" number of UIView Object in my application.I can able to drag, drop these objects to any position in the screen & chenge change their some of property .Now i want to save all these details with persistance storage ,so that whenever i launched the application nest time, i can able to see those already created object.

So what is the best solution for this?

Also is their any sample application available for this form which i can take reference?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do it this way.

```
// Create an array to store the properties
NSMutableArray *viewProperties = [NSMutableArray array]; 

// Loop through all the views
for (UIView *view in views) {

    // Create a dictionary for each view
    NSMutableDictionary *dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

    // Store the properties in the dictionary
    [dict setValue:NSStringFromCGRect(view.frame) forKey:@"ViewFrame"];
    ...

    // Add the dictionary to the array
    [viewProperties addObject:dict];
}

// Finally add the array to persistence
[userDefaults setValue:viewProperties forKey:@"ViewProperties"];
```

Later you can get the array from persistence and create the views with the properties.

```
NSMutableArray *viewProperties = [userDefaults valueForKey:@"ViewProperties"]; 

for (NSDictionary *dict in viewProperties) {

    UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] init];
    NSString *frameAsString = [dict valueForKey:@"ViewFrame"];
    view.frame = CGRectFromString(frameAsString);
    // Get other properties from dictionary and set it to view
}
```

Comment: Hey Emptystack thanks for this response,But what my requirement is once user completed his task he can save all his drawings.Then he can again make another new drawing and save it(Drawing 1, Drawing 2,Drawing 3....). Finally if he wants he can see all his savings in a splitview controller and if he wants he can able to edit & save his existing drawing.

Comment: How would this look like in Swift nowadays?